# Get ALl Contact Views of Salesforce using c# Soap API

Tags: c#

How can I get List of All Views in Contact tab of salesforce.
and contacts of each views.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

The List Views that you see on the Contacts tab can be found in the Contact.object metadata XML file.  For information connection C# to the Metadata API, see here:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/

I'm not aware of a way you can "run" or "query" a list view so as to receive a result set outside of using standard set controllers or custom controllers in apex/vf.  You might be better off constructing a SOQL query based on the List View definition (yes, by placing eyeballs on the List View and typing out the query).  It might be relatively easy to get a SELECT FROM WHERE out of the XML for the list view, so if it's worth it to be that dynamic, parse out the contents of the  tags in Contact.object.

Comment: Hii addedd metada API wsdl. But unable to initialize it with userid and password. Please help

Comment: Hi I addedd metadata API to my web application  I am unable to initialize it please help

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely query on Listview object and then filter on Sobjecttype ='contact' and isSoqlcompatible = true but you cannot get all the contacts in each view. For each contact in the list view, you can do that by using Metadata API.

Below is the SOQL query which you can use for it --

select CreatedById, CreatedDate, DeveloperName, Id, IsSoqlCompatible, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, LastReferencedDate, LastViewedDate, Name, NamespacePrefix, SobjectType, SystemModstamp from ListView where Sobjecttype ='contact'

Comment: Hi I addedd metadata API to my web application I am unable to initialize it please help